# Max value in column A, when 2 conditions in column B and C

Tags: r, conditional-statements, max

I am trying to get the max value in "Mean" column, but only from the rows, where the task is "Standard" and the Target is "A". Any help on that?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is stored in a `data.frame` called `df`, you can do the follwing:

```
max(df$Mean[df$Task == "Standard" & df$Target == "A])
```

Comment: When calculating the mean for each Target, I then filter the df  `samplesAS1 <-  df %>%  filter(CT <= maxctinA & Target == "A")` 
`samplesAS2 <- df  %>%  filter(CT < maxctinB &  Target == "B")` etc. I then need to combine all this in a df, is there a smart way to do that, instead of doing that separately for 12x targets adn use `rbind`

Answer (score 0):

We could also `filter` the data first and then get the `max`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    filter(Task == "Standard", Target == "A") %>%
    summarise(Max = max(Mean))
```